# B-Trees insertion

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

How do I add 35?

How do I know whether to move a key up(up to the node with 34 and 78, and if I do that, which key do I move up) and make more children(to fulfill the "A non-leaf node with k children contains k−1 keys." rule)

OR

just split up the 39,44,56,74(and 35) node into three children, like what I did in step 8.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cwJOdMd.png]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the insertion procedure is the following:
Find a position (node). Insert. Split if necessary. In this case 39,44,56,74 becomes 35,39,44,56,74. You need to split now: the new nodes are 35,39 and 56, 74 and the parent is now 34,44,78

Look at this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coRJrcIYbF4).